# representing wildcards on c#

Tags: c#, regex, oracle, wildcard

I'm trying to implement the two oracle wildcards "%" and "_ " on my c# program using the Regex class. The problem is when I have the wildcard "_" because I need to accept ONLY ONE character but it returns true everytime that I have AT LEAST ONE character. Can you please help me?

Here's my code:

```
string filter, string1;

string wildcard1 = "[" + "\\d | " + "\\n | " + "\\s |" + "\\w]+";
string wildcard2 = "[" + "\\d | " + "\\n |" + "\\s | " + "\\w]{1}";

filter = Regex.Replace(filter, "%", wildcard1);
filter = Regex.Replace(filter, "_", wildcard2);

Regex regex1 = new Regex(filter, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

MatchCollection a = regex1.Matches(string1);

if (regex1.IsMatch(string1))
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand you..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to make these two conversions:

- `%` to `.*`, which means, "any character, any number of times"
- `_` to `.` which means "any character (one time by default if you don't specify otherwise)"

You also have to add `^` at the start and `$` at the end, to force to match the whole string, and not a part inside it.

And finally, and this is very important, you have to [escape the original string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx). If you don't do it, any special character will be processed by the regex. I.e. a dot `.` in original string will be interpreted "as any character" in the regular expression.

For example, if you have this SQL LIKE string:

```
  Hello, %, is your inital _?
```

You have to convert it to:

```
  ^Hello, .*, is your inital .\?$
```

(This will match strings like "Hello, John, is your initial J?")

First, you have to escape it, so that the `?` and any other special character is escaped with backslash `\`.

And then replace `%` and `_` and add the start and end of string characters (`^`and `$`).

Be also aware that you can create a regex with options, and one of this options let you specify if it's case sensitive or not. This will also be neccesary to mimic Oracle behaviour.

Finally, use [IsMatch(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y21t6y4.aspx) method instead of Match.

Answer (score 0):

With such regex you will get a match if any substring matches. Thus if you ask for `abc_` and the input string is `abcde`, it will match too, because the substring `abcd` matches. Wrap your filter with `^` and `$` to avoid this.

Besides that, making initial replacement, when building your Regex, like here:

```
filter = Regex.Replace(filter, "%", wildcard1);
filter = Regex.Replace(filter, "_", wildcard2);
```

is asking for trouble, unless you make sure that characters you replace are not regex special characters. Just use normal string replacement for this.

Plus, you can just use `regex.IsMatch` instead of `Matches`.

Comment: I change my regex to: string wildcard2 = "[\\d\\n\\s\\w]$ | ^[\\d\\n\\s\\w]"; but it doesn't work. Can you please help me out?

Comment: `string filter = "^" + filter.Replace("_", "[your_regex_here]") + "$"`. Your regex can be what you use, or simply `.`, which matches any character. Please post examples how you test it and which strings don't work next time.

Comment: with this solution it works for: string1="patolo cli patolo", filter="_pat". It returns false. Thats correct but if i change the string1 to "zpatolo cli patolo" it returns false again and it should return true...